# Python for loop that cycles through a excel sheet

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to create a for loop that cycles through each Cell of a excel spread sheet. Pulls data from that sheet, and then puts it in a list.

Then a separate for loop that cycles through the list and distributes the data into a separate sheet.

I know how I can do it individually one by one That is kinda what I have right now in my code.

```
import openpyxl
import xlrd
import xlwt
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Z:\Public\Safety\SafetyDataPullProject\TestFile.xlsx')
type(wb)
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
a = sheet['E5']

#Data From Old Sheets
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('Z:\Public\Safety\SafetyDataPullProject\TestFile.xlsx')
type(wb)
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')




#New Excel Sheet Creation
book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding="utf-8")
sheet1 = book.add_sheet("Current")
sheet1.write(0, 0, "BFI4 AM CARE EOS REPORT", style0)
sheet1.write(0, 6,(time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")), style0)

sheet1.write(1, 0, 'Encounter Type', style1)
sheet1.write(1, 3, "Day Shift", style1)
sheet1.write(1, 4, "Night Shift", style1)
sheet1.write(1, 5, "Totals", style1)
sheet1.write(1, 6, "WTD", style1)


sheet1.write(5, 3, "Day Shift", style1)
sheet1.write(5, 4, "Night Shift", style1)
sheet1.write(5, 5, "Totals", style1)
sheet1.write(5, 6, "WTD", style1)

sheet1.write(2, 0 , "New Wrk Related Injury",style1)
sheet1.write(2, 3 , a.value)
sheet1.write(3, 0 , "Wrk Related Follow-up")
sheet1.write(4, 0 , "Missed Follow-up")
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example, doing all with `openpyxl`:

```
# Old Sheet
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

from openpyxl.styles import Font, colors, PatternFill
style = {'font': Font(color=colors.BLACK)}
style1 = {'font':Font(color=colors.WHITE, bold=True,italic=True),
          'fill':PatternFill(start_color=colors.RED,end_color=colors.RED,fill_type='solid')
         }

data = [
    ["BFI4 AM CARE EOS REPORT", '', '', '', '', '', (time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))],
    ['Encounter Type', '', '', "Day Shift", "Night Shift", "Totals", "WTD"],
    ["New Wrk Related Injury", '', '', '', '', '', ''],
    ["Wrk Related Follow-up", '', '', '', '', '', ''],
    ["Missed Follow-up", '', '', '', '', '', ''],
    ['', '', '', "Day Shift", "Night Shift", "Totals", "WTD"]
    ]

# Copy Data From Old Sheet
for dRow in range(2, 5):
    for dCol in range(3, 7):
        data[dRow][dCol] = ws.cell(row=dRow+3, column=dCol+2).value

# New Sheet Creation
ws1 = wb.create_sheet("Current")
for row, rData in enumerate(data, 1):
    ws1.append(rData)
    for c, rD in enumerate(rData,1):
        cell = ws1.cell(row=row, column=c)
        if row == 1:
            cell.font = style1['font']
            cell.fill = style1['fill']
        else:
            cell.font = style['font']

wb.save('test.xlsx')
```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2 - openpyxl: 2.4.1 - LibreOffice: 4.3.3.2***

Comment: Thank you so much @stovfl !! Do you think you could help me understand this though? I want to add on to it, to change the str in the list into int, so I can pull from another sheet and make it just add onto whatever is in the cell. I feel like I wont be able to because Im looking at this code and getting a little confused.

Comment: There is no difference using `string` or `int`. If you pull `int`, `openpyxl` will write `int`.